# Did I interpret this wiki article on spherical interpolation correctly?

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, interpolation, spheres, spherical-trigonometry

In Lua pseudocode, I believe the wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp) is saying that the formula is used in the following way:

```
-- assume a and b are unit vectors
local a = Vector3.new( ... );
local b = Vector3.new( ... );

function slerp( a, b, t )
    local omega = Math.acos( a:Dot( b ) );
    local sinOmega = Math.sin( omega );
    return ( Math.sin( ( 1 - t ) * omega ) / sinOmega ) * a + ( Math.sin( omega * t ) / sinOmega ) * b 
end

slerp( a, b, .5 ); -- returns a vector that represents a point on the sphere interpolated halfway between a and b.
```

Comment: You will get far more views if you mention a Slerp function that is actually defined. Unfortunately not everyone her is a computer programmer so you might have to post this on another SE as well

Comment: Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/